# Find a random string from a string via regex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings in the format below and would like to capture the portion between `/d/` and `/edit` using regex:

```
/presentation/d/1JHjE6pWJRujtMQaXcL92HBD8ZKq35au8moEv_zP2D_-0/edit
```

When I use this `(\/d\W)(.*)\b\/`, I'm able to capture `/d/1JHjE6pWJRujtMQaXcL92HBD8ZKq35au8moEv_zP2D_-0/`; not the actual portion I need (strictly the string between `/d/` and `/edit`).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not just search for that exact string? That would be easier I imagine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Provided you always have the string you want to get between a `/d/` and an `/edit`, you can capture it with this regex: `(.*\/d\/)(.*)(\/edit.*)`; it should be the second group.

Below is an illustration of how you can get it:

```js
var data = "/presentation/d/1JHjE6pWJRujtMQaXcL92HBD8ZKq35au8moEv_zP2D_-0/edit";
my_preferred_string = data.match(/(.*\/d\/)(.*)(\/edit.*)/)[2];
console.log(my_preferred_string);
```

---

Explaining the regex, `/(.*\/d\/)(.*)(\/edit.*)/g`:

Here, we have three groups; the groups are confined within brackets as in: `(the group elements)`, where *the group elements* represents the desired matches.

The 1st group is captured with `(.*\/d\/)`.

In the expression for that group, `.*` is used to capture any character with the exception of line terminators. In that same portion, we've made use of the quantifier `*` for matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible. Then, the `\/` as a match for the `/` character (case sensitive), where the preceding `\` is an escape, followed by the letter `d` (case sensitive, to match specifically *d* as a character), and ending with `\/`, just as before the `d`.

The 2nd group which is the actual portion we are interested in is captured with the `(.*)`, where `.*` is just as explained above in capturing the preceding expression.

The 3rd group is captured with `(\/edit.*)`, where `\/` and `.*` are equally as explained above (group 1), and the `edit` as a character match for *edit* (case sensitive).

Finally, the `g` is a flag (Global pattern flags). It help us get all matches and does not return after we got the first match of our regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following pattern:

```
/presentation/d/(.*?)/edit
```

```js
var input = '/presentation/d/1JHjE6pWJRujtMQaXcL92HBD8ZKq35au8moEv_zP2D_-0/edit';
var rx = /\/presentation\/d\/(.*?)\/edit/g;
var arr = rx.exec(input);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester